# Drone with authonomous charging and able to fly on flight plan / trajectory

Tags: charging, autonomous

Would you recommend a drone which can surveil agricultural areas regularly?

It should be able:

- autonomus charge itself, without human help
- flight on trajectory / preprogrammed flight plan
- not too expensive

Answer (score 0):

NO.  Total pipe dream.

The autonomous charge itself, without human help: Not advised. Look at https://mttr.net/ - they have some systems (or at least did).

Several problems with "self-charging" exist, I will outline a few key items:

- Need a cool-down period before re-charge, don't charge "hot" batteries. So add in some thermal sensors and software.
- How are you going to charge? Inductive: bad transfer rate for a charge, not efficient, fire risk. If you "plug in" (direct connect), there are several specific design patterns, and they bring high failure rates. One is a touch charge aka a fire waiting to happen (such as EarBuds charge in their case).  If a proper "plug" is used (best way to go), then you have to make a cradle and additional mechanical "stuff" to get the drone "plugged in."

If you look at the FAA regs, this request also violates many enforceable mechanical and safety protocols. Post/pre-flight inspection, CRM values, etc., are all proper protocols.

Pre-programmed flight: Unless you are there and spotting your request is 100% illegal.  (Have fun getting the exemption, I have a lawyer friend who can help, and $50k to start)

Not expensive; good luck on that one.  I would estimate a minimum $50-100k to do legally and safe.

What you want to do is possible, but you will be breaking many laws, and your "system" will be insanely expensive.